# Lazy One-To-One Spring JPA and building "dynamic" JSON

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

I'm developing a relatively large project using Spring Boot, and in a general way I'm pretty happy with it, but I'm having some problems that in my mind should't be a problem.

1. First of all, One-To-One Relationship. It's frustrating that it doesn't work as it should (at least in my mind).

   I have two entities, `User` and `UserProfile`, for example. They have One-To-One relationship, but most of the time I only need the `User` data, but it fetches (no matter what I try, and oh boy, I tried the world suggestions on every post for 5 pages of Google).

   So there is my first question, is there a way to be able to lazy fetch One-To-One relationship in JPA and Spring? (Because most of the posts are more than 2-3 years old).
2. The other problem I have is about to build a JSON response in a "dynamic" way. I did some stuff using Rails and was very happy with `JBuilder` or even the `to_json` that gave me the ability to build the json response depending on the controller and my needs at the moment.

   In Spring I saw the following solutions:

   - `Jackson @JsonView` (which doesn't solve entirely my problem because the responses are not that static and a attribute can't be assigned to multiple views (as far as I understood the concept));
   - setting to null attributes that I don't want on the response (using this, but I's just too ugly and looks like a wrong walkthrough);
   - or building `HashMap` like I build `.json.jbuilder` on Rails (but this kills my performance as sometimes it has relationships so a lot of `for` to build the json, and also this looks like a ugly walkthrough).

I'm looking for some directions from someone that someday may have encountered one of this problems because it's killing me not being able so solve problems that in my mind should not be this hard.

**EDIT 1**

Already tried to add `optional = false` on the `@OneToOne` annotation to solve the Eager load of OneToOne relationship as @snovelli suggested. Example:

```
@OneToOne(optional=false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public UserProfile getUserProfile(){ ... }
```

Comment: Your question contains two unrelated questions. You should pick one and extract the other into a separate question. Anyway, this is the first SO question in which I added two answers. :)

Comment: I thought about that, but I had some questions like this ones but no one answered so I posted this one knowing that I would have to put a bounty so it could be answered, and as I don't have too many points to spare on bounties, I put the the two in one question :( But at least I think these are two questions that everybody that are not wizards at Spring and JPA may have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the join column is not in the table to which a parent in a one-to-one association is mapped, then the association [cannot be lazy](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one). The reason is that JPA provider cannot determine whether to create the proxy, so that it can load the object when accessed later, or leave the `null` value.

Even if the association is not optional, JPA provider has to determine the id of the associated entity instance to store it in the proxy. Thus it has to go to the associated table anyway.

Solutions:

1. [Byte code instrumentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties). Not widely adopted approach though.
2. Use one-to-many and handle empty list as `null`, otherwise use `list.get(0)`. You can of course encapsulate this in the entity class (getter returns the only element of the list or `null`). The drawback is that you will have to treat this as collection in JPQL queries.
3. Use [`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html) instead of a foreign key. If the association is not optional (`optional = false`), then JPA provider knows that there is an associated child with the same PK, so it will just store the PK of the parent as the id of the child in the proxy. Obviously, you can't use two independent id generators for both of the entities, otherwise PKs may be different. This is the best approach if it meets your requirements.
4. Add the foreign key in the parent table also (making the relationship bidirectional in the database as well). The drawback is that you now basically have two independent associations which you have to maintain. Also, there is the performance cost of updating two tables instead of one (and the foreign keys have to be nullable).
5. Map parent entity to a database view that joins parent table with the child table and contains all parent columns plus id of child table:

   ```
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "<child id in the view>", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Child child;
   ```

Comment: It worked fine with the third suggestion. Appeared a problem with my Id type (its saying that is receiving an integer but expecting a Long) but after changing the type it worked (that's something that I'll look up later), the important is that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @augustoccesar You're welcome. Keep in mind that you can't use two independent id generators for both of the entities with the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, the associated entities must have the same PK.

Comment: By saying the same PK you mean that on the creating the two are using the same increment as in if a `User` has an `id == 1` then the related `UserProfile` has the `id == 1` ?

Comment: But in the example both entities have `@GeneratedValue`, or I understood wrong?

Comment: @augustoccesar Actually, that tutorial seems to be wrong. Take a look at [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/). Here it is shown how a `foreign` id generation strategy is used for this purpose. However, the most straightforward way I would choose is to omit the id generator completely and use [`@MapsId`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9925895/4754790) to map the id from the associated entity.

Comment: I see.. Now I understood. It seems to be simpler to just assert that they are equal by assigning on creation. Thanks for all the attention :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 'dynamic' JSON: Use [DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-data-transfer-object).

This has the advantage of tailoring the objects to be serialized to the exact needs of the client consuming the resulting JSON. Also, the domain model (Hibernate entities) is decoupled from the JSON (de)serialization logic, allowing the two to evolve independently.

Comment: Thats a great pattern! Did not knew about that. In some way I was manipulating the responses, but using HashMap's. Using DTOs look more correct and maintainable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `@OneToOne`: are you worried more by amount of data or multiple queries against the DB?

In former case (if that's possible when using Spring Roo) you could try a workaround with `@ManyToOne` relation modelling (one-to-one is a special case of many-to-one, isn't it).

In latter case you could use `@Embeddable` to decompose entity like User into multiple classes while keeping the data together in the DB, so only one query would be used to fetch it.