# Does anybody know the usage of table attribute in @JoinColumn annotation? Should i give the actual table name or the entity name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a problem in using @ManyToOne relation, because my foreign key and primary key have same name, so Hibernate is considering the one i mapped as the current table's column name. 
So i thought i will use table attribute of @JoinColumn annotations, but it seems to be not working. I gave actual table for it's value, but it is not taking. Tried the Class-name as well.
below are the Entities. You can see PRJ_NBR is same in both tables. So when i try to run the project i'm getting error like **Cannot find the expected secondary table: no HEAD available**

If I remove *table* attribute from @JoinColumn I'm getting error - **Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.jpademo.Detail column: PRJ_NBR (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")**

```
@Entity(name="Head")
@Table(name = "HEAD")
public class QuoteHead {
@Id
@Column(name = "PRJ_NBR")
private Integer projNumber;
@Column(name = "CUS_SYS_ID")
private Integer cusSysId;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "head", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = 
true)
private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAIL")
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Detail {
@Transient
private Integer projectNumber;
@Transient
private Integer itemNumber;
@Transient
private Integer sequenceNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PRJ_NBR", table = "HEAD")
private Head head;

@JsonIgnore
@EmbeddedId
private DetailCompositeId id;
}
@Embeddable
public class DetailCompositeId implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Column(name = "PRJ_NBR")
private Integer projectNumber;
@Column(name = "ITM_NBR")
private Integer itemNum;
@Column(name = "SEQ_NBR")
private Integer sequenceNumber;
}
```

Comment: Please share your entities (and the relevant db schema as well). It's not quite clear what you mean by: 'my foreign key and primary key have same name'

Comment: Will update the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove 'table' and try putting insertable="false" , updatable="false"  then I think it should work

Comment: This worked after adding annotation @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED) in DAO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `@MapsId` annotation.

See this post: [can someone please explain me @MapsId in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923643/can0-someone-please-explain-me-mapsid-in-hibernate)

You can remove `@JoinColumn` in your `@ManyToOne` mapping and replace it with `@MapsId`, as shown below:

```
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("projectNumber")
private Head head;
```

Comment: Didn't work. Since i'm having composite key i'm getting below error.
 
Foreign key (FKDEBBB5FE3D4F36A7: DETAIL [head_PRJ_NBR])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (HEAD [ITM_NBR,head_PRJ_NBR,SEQ_NBR])