# Hibernate joined table inheritance im combination with OneToOne and @MapsId

Tags: spring, hibernate

Using Hibernate in combination with mysql.

When I try to create a @OneToOne Relationship from a child of a joined table inheritance while also using @MapsId to map the Id of the joined table child.

For testing it, I have even created a test project with the following structure:

#### Joined Table Parent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_joined_bases")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class AJoinedBase implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

#### Joined Table Child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_joined_children")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class JoinedChild extends AJoinedBase {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "note", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private NoteContent content;
}
```

#### OneToOne-Extension

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_joined_child_extensions")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JoinedChildExtension implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private JoinedChild joinedChild;
}
```

However, I cannot even start the spring boot application without it throwing an error. The problem seems to be that Hibernate cannot find the key-columns of the referenced Entity (here: JoinedChild) and thus throws a NullPointerException when calling columnIterator.next();. I believe that this happens because the key is saved in a wrappedValue due to the Joined Table Inheritance.
Can anyone help me with that or is this an issue with the Hibernate ORM?

#### StackTrace

When building the project, I get the following error:

```
2018-08-10 18:54:20.611  WARN 9836 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
[...]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.studynote.StudynoteBackendApplication.main(StudynoteBackendApplication.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.linkJoinColumnWithValueOverridingNameIfImplicit(TableBinder.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.doSecondPass(PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1640) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why do you think that you must use MapsId ?

Comment: Because I want the related Entity (JoinedChildExtension) to automatically get the id from the other side of the OneToOne (JoinedChild).

Comment: Can you post the underlying data model

Answer (score 1):

@MapId is designed for Embeddable id
for more details you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923643/can-someone-please-explain-me-mapsid-in-hibernate)
I've fixed this for my problem replacing @MapId("nameOfColumn") with @JoinColumn("nameOfColumn")

Answer (score 1):

`@MapsId` is perfectly fine for using with `@OneToOne` relationship. See these articles for usage:

[One-to-One Relationship in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one#spk-model).

[The best way to map a @OneToOne relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

However, the NoSuchElementException is in the stacktrace probably because using `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` with `@MapsId` together. The problem is described in these Hibernate issue tickets:
[HHH-13335](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13335), [HHH-13295](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13295), and [HHH-7135](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7135).

Currently,  all three tickets are unresolved. We have to wait for this bug to be fixed. In the mean time, you can use `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` or `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` with `@MapsId` as a workaround. See [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) for the usage of these InheritanceType alternatives.