# How to use @Id of one @Entity in another @Entity in a @OneToOne relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

How to use the primary key defined in one @Entity class in another @Entity class in @OneToOne relationship in hibernate

Till now I've this...I do not want to use @Id in phoneNumber of the Phone class. How to do that? And are @JoinColumn and @MapsId annotations mandatory(what do they exactly do)? Thank you all.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private Phone phone;
...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Phone {
    private int phoneNumber;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;
...
}
```

Edited: while mapped to tables, I want the table `Phone` to have a column that is a primary key for itself while being the same value as that of the primary key of table `User`.

Comment: kinda hard to tell what you want to achieve...
Try to rephrase the question / make an example of what you want

Comment: If you don't want to use `@Id` in `Phone`, does that then mean that phone records in your database should not have identity? Why don't you then just add a phone field to a user?

Comment: [@MapsId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923643/can-someone-please-explain-me-mapsid-in-hibernate). `@JoinColumn` seems to be used right. No you can't do what you want. You always need `@Id`

Comment: @Zeromus added a brief statement to make it clearer.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I want id but not from the member variables of Phone class should be the same as that of User class

Comment: @robinhoodjr, "i want id of Phone to be the same as that of User" - you can't do that if your user has several phones. It's called Id for a reason - its value should be unique in any given table.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov damn I've gone insane. It's 5 in the morning.if it we're onetoone, how to achieve this?

Comment: @robinhoodjr, `@MapsId` already means primary key is shared, itsn't it? Speaking from having read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923643/can-someone-please-explain-me-mapsid-in-hibernate

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks. I need some rest and fresh pair of eyes, it seems.

Comment: Perhaps reading up on the hibernate framework and how it works will answer the answer the question ' are `@JoinColumn `and `@MapsId` annotations mandatory(what do they exactly do)?'.